# How to listen to certain event in iOS socket io

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, socket.io

I'm using https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc
as an iOS implementation of socket io. I connect via this line of code

```
[socketIO connectToHost:@"io.server.com/" onPort:0];
```

and listen to those two events via these two lines of code.

```
[socketIO sendEvent:@"event1Name" withData:nil];
[socketIO sendEvent:@"event2Name" withData:nil];
```

now in delegate method

```
- (void) socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveEvent(%@)", packet.name);
}
```

I want to know which event I am receiving from `event1Name` or `event2Name` ?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you find solution of this?

Comment: @Maul I had to implement it myself. Simply I kept a dictionary with key as eventNAme and value as callbackBlock (or SEL) to call when a message with its key recieved.
I also had to implement a register method that will add the eventName/blockHandler pair to my dictionary.

Comment: Can you please paste some code? it will more help to me. Thanks in advance